# How to take a photo in a specific aspect ratio, such us 1:1, with Flutter camera

Tags: flutter, dart, camera

I want to see the camera with aspect ratio 1:1 in CameraPreview, but even after that, when I see the shot picture it must be 1:1.

I tried using Transform.scale and set the scale, but it only changes the CameraPreview, not the photo after being taken.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.